# Limit of $\int\limits_0^1 (1-x^2)^n dx$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: integration, limits

Find the limit of $\int\limits_0^1 {{{\left( {1 - {x^2}} \right)}^n}dx} $ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @nicomezi I've tried and now I'm getting stuck with $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{C_n^k{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{x^{2k + 1}}}}{{2k + 1}}}$

Comment: Hint: let $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ arbitrary. Split the integral into $[0, \varepsilon]$ and $(\varepsilon,1]$ intervals. In the former the integral is bounded by $\varepsilon$, while in the second $(1-x^{2})^{n} \rightarrow 0$ uniformly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x = \sin(t)$, then:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_0^1 {{{\left( {1 - {x^2}} \right)}^n}dx}}$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_0^{\pi\over2} {{{\left( {1 - {\sin^2t}} \right)}^n}d(\sin t)}}$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_0^{\pi\over2} {{\cos^{2n}(t)\ }d(\sin t)}}$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_0^{\pi\over2} {{\cos^{2n+1}(t)\ }dt}}$$
then, according to [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals):
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{(2n)!!\over(2n+1)!!} = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be given by $f_n (x) = (1-x^2)^n$. Notice that $\lim _{n \to \infty} f_n = f$ where $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x = 0 \\ 0, & x \ (0,1] \end{cases}$. Notice also that this $f$ is integrable and $\int _0 ^1 f(x) \ \Bbb d x = 0$. Now just apply Lebesgue's [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to get that your integrals converge to $0$.